# Currency get symbol not giving correct symbol for USD, android?

Tags: android, currency, currency-formatting

I am using the below code to get the currency symbol for USD

```
 Currency currency=Currency.getInstance("USD");
currency.getSymbol();
```

I get the output as `US$`

But I want the output as `$`

So what's wrong in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should resolve issue :

```
Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(Locale.US);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also mention currency symbol in `string.xml` under resource like,

```
<string name="us">\u0024</string>
```

Then use it to display like

```
String dollar = getResources().getString(R.string.us);
```